# Как в приложении на C# WPF иметь доступ к функциям javascript и наоборот?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf

Как в приложении на wpf C# встроить браузер,в котором иметь доступ к переменным самой программы?
суть в том,что хочу часть функционала сделать на javascript/html но что б был доступ к функциям самой программы из javascript и наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно документации по [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx), для вызова скрипта JS из кода C# можно воспользоваться функцией [InvokeScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc452443(v=vs.110).aspx), для обратной операции есть свойство [ObjectForScripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx)